# Setting up subdomain for local development

Tags: apache, xampp, virtual-hosts

I have XAMPP installed for local development and I'd like to create a sub domain for each project. In my apache vhosts config I've put this:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/
ServerName localhost
ServerAdmin admin@localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost nexus.localhost:80>
DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/nexus/
ServerName nexus.localhost
ServerAdmin admin@nexus.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

And in my Windows hosts file:

```
# development
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 nexus.localhost
```

localhost works as normal. As in, if I go to `http://localhost/project_name` everything works fine. However, if I navigate to `http://nexus.localhost/` I just get `Object not found!` errors.

What could be wrong here? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost says that the `<VirtualHost>` directive should contain the IP address, so try this instead:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/
ServerName localhost
ServerAdmin admin@localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/nexus/
ServerName nexus.localhost
ServerAdmin admin@nexus.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: That's better, however both VirtualHosts seem to point to the same document root. For example, if I go to `http://nexus.localhost/`, it shows the root directory, not `/nexus`.

Comment: @MartinHoe Do you have a `NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1` line? (http://sawmac.com/xampp/virtualhosts/)